# Remove entity through parent saving

Tags: hibernate, jpa

How can I remove `CardParameter` from my database, by executing code like:

```
Card card=(Card)sesion.get(id, Card.class);
Set<CardParameter> parameters=card.getCardParameters();
//Some code, that removes a few elements from parameters collection
session.save(card);
```

When i'm saving parent entity children correctly adds, updates, but they doesn't removes. Here is my parent and child entities:

```
@Table(name = "card")
@Entity
public class Card {
....
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "card", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference("cardParameter")
    private Set<CardParameter> cardParameters;
}

@Table(name = "card_parameter")
@Entity
public class CardParameter {
....

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "card")
    @JsonBackReference("cardParameter")
    private Card card;
}
```

Comment: Please, post the code that removes the elements from the collection.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic, Nothing special. I know, `Set` doesn't have such method, but if we imagine that `cardParameters` is `List<CardParameter>` it will be: `cardParameters.remove(2);`

Comment: Good luck with debugging using imagination! :)

Comment: Anyway, is `CardParameter` referenced from any other entity?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic, no, `CardParameter` related only with `Card`. About imigination. Actualy I'm sending `Card` to client-side as JSON **Then client can remove some parameters from `Card` entity JSON.** Next step: my JSON deserializes to `Card` entity and i'm saving it.

Comment: I wanna to hibernate will have seen differences between `CardParameters` set of original `Card` object and edited `Card` object, and removes a redundant `CardParameters`.

Comment: So, you are saving a brand new `Card` instance together with brand new `CardParameter` collection (that's what `Session.save` does after all anyway)? Then it is expected that the original card and card parameters are the same as they were before the new ones are saved.

Comment: Or, more likely, you are deserializing a brand new `Card` instance and you are not merging the changes in it to the instance that is already in the persistence context. Please, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must to use `orphanRemoval = true` in @OneToMany relation. I don't know why, but about 5 hours ago it have not helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not merging the changes in the deserialized `Card` instance to the instance that is already in the persistence context.

Try:

```
Card card = (Card) sesion.get(id, Card.class);
Card deserializedCard = // serialize, change and deserialize
session.merge(deserializedCard);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I also have tried `update(deserializedCard);`.